# Hide folders in online compiler

Tags: amazon-web-services, directory, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have developed a PHP application which serves as an online code compiler (in C, Java and Python) and hosted it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The user can type his code and submit to execute it. Then the server will return the output of the execution of his code.

When the user type `my_app_url/some_dir`, the website will raise 403 error. However, the user can still list all the files and directories from `/var/www/html` by writing some appropriate code. I know I can process the output of the code to hide them, but is there any better way to do it?

All directories and files are owned by `root:root`. The permission mode is `755 for directory` and `644 for file`. The PHP application is running as `webapp`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that it's not a good idea to allow people to run arbitrary code on your server instance. Depending on who has access to your service, and how well it is controller or monitored, you may run into all kinds of trouble (i.e. people sending spam, doing DOS attacks or hosting illegal stuff on your server), as they can run any kind of code on your machine.

Coming back to your question, you need to somehow make sure the code that is uploaded only does stuff that you allow. In Java you could use a custom security policy (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html), for example in order to disallow file access from the code. Additionally you'd need to set some limits on memory usage and run time, and kill any program that exceeds them. I'm not that familiar with C and Python, possibly there are similar mechanisms there to control what a process is doing. Platforms like TopCoder allow running your own code on their machines, implementing such a mechanism securely is however most certainly a very complex task.